# Recommended CS books for high school

Tags: textbook

What are the popular books for teaching CS in high schools in the USA?

The programming language doesn't matter.

I'm asking because I'm looking for more exercises to give to my students.

I am a CS teacher not in the USA, and I want to expand the variety of my books.

In my country, there is one company whose books almost all high schools learn with for CS.

I am looking for a CS books recommendation. What's common in the USA high schools.

Comment: Do you literally mean "popular" or something like "effective"? What is your goal here? Likewise, By CS are you focused just on programming, or the wider field?

Comment: If someone is a teacher, he can write in which books he uses

Comment: Hi 3SAT, this question is not getting much attention because it is just too broad.  We use all sorts of different books for all sorts of different things.  Start with learning goals. Are you trying to teach OOP? Imperative programming? Computational thinking? Book choice is typically the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Runestone Interactive](https://runestone.academy/)

They have several [books](https://runestoneinteractive.org/pages/library.html).

In particular in the US there are college credits that can be earned with special high school courses ([Advanced Placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Placement)). One of the courses for this is called [CS Awesome](https://csawesome.runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/csawesome/index.html). There is also a [teacher web site](https://www.csawesome.org/) for CS Awesome.